# Vector Problem, Vector geometry

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be points in space such that vector $$\vec{OC} =\frac 13 \vec{OA} +\frac 23 \vec{OB}$$ Show that $C$ is twice as
>   far from $A$ as it is from $B$.

Comment: What have you attempted? Isn't it trivial that if $C=\frac{A+2B}{3}$ then $|C-A| = 2|C-B|$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\vec{OC} =\frac 13 \vec{OA} +\frac 23 \vec{OB} \\ \implies \begin{cases}\vec{AC} = \vec{OC} - \vec{OA} =\frac 13 \vec{OA} +\frac 23 \vec{OB} - \vec{OA} = \frac 23\left(\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}\right) = \frac 23 \vec{AB} \\ \vec{BC} = \vec{OC} - \vec{OB} =\frac 13 \vec{OA} +\frac 23 \vec{OB} - \vec{OB} = \frac 13\left(\vec{OA}-\vec{OB}\right) = \frac 13 \vec{BA}\end{cases}$$
Because $\left\|\vec{BA}\right\|=\left\|\vec{AB}\right\|$, we have
$$\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{\left\|\vec{AC}\right\| = 2\left\|\vec{BC}\right\|}$$